# exact value of $\arccos\left({\sqrt{2}\over \sqrt{3}}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do i find the exact value of $$\arccos\left({\sqrt2\over \sqrt{3}}\right)$$
Any ideas on how to find the exact value of the expression without using a calculator?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem to have [a closed form](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcos%28sqrt%282%2F3%29%29).

Comment: ok thanks, thats what i thought too

Comment: fwiw , it is also = $ \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} ,$ problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have the question wrong. Here is how you would solve it:

Let $\theta = \arccos\left({\sqrt2\over \sqrt{3}}\right)$, so that $\cos \theta = {\sqrt2\over \sqrt{3}}$.

1. What is $\cos^2\theta$?
2. What is $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta-1$?
3. What is $2\theta$?

Step $3$ is problematic! I expected $\cos 2\theta$ to evaluate to something obvious, like $\frac12$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ or $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$. But it doesn't. Are you sure about $\sqrt2\over \sqrt{3}$?

Answer (score 1):

How about evaluating in terms of a complex log?
$$
\arccos\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\pi}{2}+i\log  \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}} \right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible to find the *exact* value without a calculator, but you can get a rather close estimate if you

1. Use the power series \begin{equation}
   \left (\frac{\pi}{2} \right)- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ {{2n}\choose{n}} \left ( \frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2} \right )^{2n+1}}{4^n (2n+1)} 
   \end{equation}

Of course this is evaluated without a calculator, we use approximate figures for the square roots.

2. Draw a triangle with adjacent $\sqrt 2$ and a hypothenuse of $\sqrt 3$, and use a protractor to measure the angle.